# Shutting off production in short term

Tags: microeconomics

could you help me to solve the task, please? The task is following.
Total costs of the сompetitive firm are $TC = Q^3 +6$ (Q in thousands \$). If the production is stopped then monthly costs are 4000\$. At what prices the company that maximising profit should shut off the production?
I know that if $P < minAVC$, then the company should stop producing. 
So $VC = Q^3$ then $AVC = \frac{Q^3}{Q} = Q^2$ and $minAVC = 0$
So I get $P<0$ that sounds stupid. And I don't even know how to use that 4000\$.
The answer should be $P<3$
Could you help me to find out how to solve this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Realistically, you can get VC=0 only if Q=0.But if Q=0, then you do NOT have AVC, because **you would divide by zero**.

Comment: "(I made a mistake, there was 'AC=Q^3', but still, not ATC)"  AC is just shorthand for ATC, as far as I know.

Comment: oh, didn't know that. it was just a typo. But still, any thoughts what should I do to get a correct answer? :D

Comment: One more thing, I think it's strange that according to function of TC the fixed costs are $6000 (when Q=0), but then you say that fixed costs will be  4000 dollars if the firm stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the problem now, your AVC(Q) is wrong. Your fixed costs are 4000, because it's what the firm will pay after it stops production. VC=TC-4=Q^3+2. Thus AVC=Q^2+2/Q. Now you should use your calculus in order to find where AVC has local positive minimum (because it doesn't have global minimum due to its hyperbolic nature).

Comment: ... and that is exactly at p=3
Thank you very much, you are a genious! ^^

Comment: @elfinorr Thanks, but are you sure that you calculated everything correctly? Shutdown price is when P=min AVC, and my calculations make me believe, that Q=3 is NOT its local minimum

Comment: But Q = 1 is, and AVC(1) = 3. It seems to be okay.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, my mistake. Everything is OK.